# Finding the domain of a function of a single variable.

Tags: calculus, functions

I was solving this problem:

> f is a function such that $f(x)=\sqrt{\frac{x-1}{x-2\{x\}}}$ where $\{x\}$ denotes the fractional part of x.
>
> Find the domain of f.

So I began as:

Case 1 (x-2{x}>0) :
$$\frac{x-1}{x-2\{x\}}\ge0$$
$$\Rightarrow x\ge1$$

For $$x-2\{x\}\gt0$$
$$\Rightarrow x\gt2\{x\}$$
as $0\le\{x\}\lt1$ therefore,
$$x\ge2$$
But, $$x-2\{x\}\gt0$$
$$\Rightarrow [x]\ge\{x\}$$
$$\Rightarrow x\ge1$$
What seems to be the error here?

Comment: Cases is good. There is maybe a little too much manipulation, but no error.  Possibly it is better to examine $x\ge 1$ first.

Comment: By the way, an editorial comment: I'm guessing you're in high school because it seems that the authors of high school textbooks are unaware that you can't derive the domain of a function from its rule. The domain is part of the definition of the function; until {\bf you} tell {\bf me} the domain of the function, you haven't told me the function at all. Hence we have endless problems of \lq\lq finding the domain" of a function based on its rule, which is impossible.

Comment: @Jason Ooo I forget to mention that the domain if not explicitly given is taken to be all real values for which the function assumes a real value.

Comment: @Shrayansh - thanks for the note, and I'm glad to hear it!

Comment: Am I mistaken in my answer below?

Comment: No it's right, I forgot to chose it as best answer.

Comment: Ok - glad to help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not follow from $x > 2\{x\}$ that $x \geq 2$.

Note that $x=1$ satisfies $x > 2\{x\}$ but $x=1$ does not satisfy $x \geq 2$.

In your deduction leading to $x \geq 2$, you forgot that $0\leq \{x\} < 1$ allows a case such as $\{x\} = 0$.